# std variant and forward declarations

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, reference-wrapper

It's my understanding that `std::variant` cannot directly hold references.

However, `std::reference_wrapper` is a fully qualified type that can be put into things like `std::vector`, and since one can make a vector of reference wrappers, I imagined that one could do the same with `std::variant`.

The following (edited to be more minimal) code generates a plethora of errors in gcc:

```
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

class Foo;
class Baz;

template<typename T> struct CRef : std::reference_wrapper<const T> {
    CRef(const T &x) : std::reference_wrapper<const T>(x)
    {
    }
};    

template<typename... Args> struct Contains : public std::variant<CRef<Args>... > {
};

struct Foo : public Contains<Baz> {

    int getSize() const;
};

struct getSizeVisitor {

    template<typename T> int operator()(CRef<T> x) const
    {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};

inline int Foo::getSize() const
{
    return std::visit(getSizeVisitor(), (*this));
}

struct Baz : public Foo {

};
```

The `CRef` template is simply a convenient wrapper around an std::reference_wrapper to a const reference, and the `Contains` template exists to help a class be made aware of all of the endpoint subclasses that the base class may at some point refer to.  In the above case, I am simply wanting a `getSize()` method, which will return the size of the actual type contained in the variant.  `Baz`, in this case, is the only endpoint class, although in practice there will be more, and they will have no common base class, which is why I require a variant, and cannot simply use a base class and employ virtual functions.

The errors generated by the compiler are visible here: https://godbolt.org/z/lcbPjB

So, I guess I'm probably doing something that isn't allowed.

The question I have is, is there a way to do what I'm trying?  I apologize in advance if my intent is unclear.  If there are problems understanding what I am trying to achieve, some feedback to that effect that specifically identifies what additional information I need to supply can be left and I shall endeavor to comply.

Bear in mind that in the actual use case, the endpoint classes are much more complex, and there will be many more functions beyond getSize(), but I expect once I have something working for this simple case, I should be able to generalize and implement the other functions correctly.

Comment: In the future, we do care about the "minimal" in [mcve]. There's a lot of code in this example that doesn't contribute to demonstrating the issue. Here's just commenting out a bunch of stuff: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/_3yDt3) (I did add one semicolon).

Comment: Example is simplified, per your request.  Your shorter reproduction identified one problem with the original, and I apologize profusely for the confusion.  A different problem emerges even when I remove the call to CRef around *this in the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much shorter reproduction of the same issue:

```
int getSize(std::variant<int, char> var)
{
    return std::visit([](auto const& x){ return sizeof(x); },
        std::cref(var));
}
```

The problem is, you're trying to pass a `reference_wrapper` to `std::visit`... but that violates the requirements of `std::visit` - it *needs* take actual `std::variant`s (in the original OP, the object is even more removed from `std::variant` - it's a reference wrapper of a type that inherits from a type that inherits from a `std::variant` - but the distance from `variant` doesn't matter).

You need to pass in the exact variant. In my short example, that's just passing `var` instead of `std::cref(var)`. In the OP, that's casting `*this` down to `variant<Ts...> const&` for the correct types `Ts...`

Comment: While this does identify one problem with the code I had originally posted (which was mistakenly constructing a reference around the variant and passing that to std visit instead of passing the variant directly), removing that still reveals that there is something else I am doing that is wrong.

Comment: @markt1964 It's the same problem - you're passing something whose type is not `variant<Ts...>`.